# How to filter while loop in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, while-loop

I stuck on this,

I want to create a table with 10 rows, each row having "same drop down menu" of 10 products. But in every row different product selected. example in first row first product in second row second product and so on. The bellow code is showing drop down menu in each row but every row have first product selected. How can I select next product for next row?

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select>
                <?php
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE featured=1 LIMIT 10";
                    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                        echo "<option>".$row["product_name"]."</option>"
                    }
                ?>
             </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <?php
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE featured=1 LIMIT 10";
                    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                        echo "<option>".$row["product_name"]."</option>"
                    }
                ?>
             </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please complete php file and database field also .

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE featured=1 LIMIT 10";  Wont work if that's how you're using it.  $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE featured=1 LIMIT 10");

Comment: the code looks redundant and unstructured you might want to fix the layout in your question by indenting

Comment: ok, I fixed the code, I mistyped here, but in my code its correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <? 
    //Only Once call to DB
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE featured=1 LIMIT 10";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query); 
    $pos = 0;
    $currentRow = 0;
    ?>

    <table>
        <tr>
            </td>
            <select>
                <?php

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                if($pos==$currentRow)
                   echo "<option selected=\"selected\">".$row["product_name"]."                     </option>";
                else
                   echo "<option>".$row["product_name"]."</option>";
                $pos++;

                }

                mysqli_data_seek( $result, 0 );
                $pos = 0;
                $currentRow++;

                ?>
            </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            </td>
            <select>
                <?php
               while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                if($pos==$currentRow)
                   echo "<option selected=\"selected\">".$row["product_name"]."                     </option>";
                else
                   echo "<option>".$row["product_name"]."</option>";
                           $pos++;

                }

                mysqli_data_seek( $result, 0 );
                $pos = 0;
                $currentRow++;
                ?>

            </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: No, It didn't worked. Only first row with drop down menu. and other rows with blank drop down menu.

Comment: Please, try again I'm added your changes and reset the pointer  for $result

Comment: This method mysql_data_seek( $result, 0 ); move the pointer so you can still loop $result http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php

Comment: Thanks, It worked but when I again made the query for second row, It's not working on single query for all rows. I need to make query for each row. Is there solution for this?

Comment: you used mysql_data_seek ($ result, 0); after each while ?

Comment: sorry, my mistake you need use mysqli_data_seek ($result, 0) I'm missed "i". No, you don't need to make query for each row. Please, let me know if you fix

Comment: Cool... That worked. Even me too didn't noticed that. I choosed your answer as "accepted answer". Thanks again for your valuable help. Have a nice day :-)

Answer (score 0):

your second while loop

```
$i=0;    
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$i++;
if($i==2)
    echo "<option selected=\"selected\">".$row["product_name"]."</option>";
else
 echo "<option>".$row["product_name"]."</option>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: your code works too, but I need to make query for each row. means 10 same query to show 10 table rows. Is there solution on this?

Comment: you are not looping on query u r looping result set.

Comment: yes, I'm looping result set. but before looping each result set in every row of table, I need to call the same query again to loop its result set. Calling single query, then looping it 10 times doesn't help. only first row is displayed. That's why I have to call same query for each row then loop it.